# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' when using parseFloat

Tags: typescript

I am getting a Argument of type 'number' is not assignable... error when I use parseFloat in my code. I have tried typing differenceBetweenDates as `string | number` and as `any`, as well as unitDateValue as `string | number` and `any`, but the error remains.

It's particualy confusing, because the error says cannot assign, and give me the variable differenceBetweenDates, when I'm not setting the variable in the code. **differenceBetweenDates** is underlined as an error, but I am actually assigning **unitDateValue**;

Here is the function in question:

```
export default function processDate(): void {
  let endDateValue: any = 10;
  let startDateValue: any = 20  
  let unitDateValue: any;
  let unit = 'day';  
  let differenceBetweenDates: any;

  // diff() will return a number
  differenceBetweenDates = endDateValue.diff(startDateValue);
  if(differenceBetweenDates > 0) {
    switch (unit) {
      case 'day': {

        // ERROR: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string';
        // ERROR: let differenceBetweenDates: any;
        unitDateValue = parseFloat( differenceBetweenDates / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) ).toFixed(0);

        // This works but is not what I want, I need to parseFloat
        // unitDateValue = ( differenceBetweenDates / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) ).toFixed(0);
        break;
      }
      case 'week': {
        // ERROR: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string';
        // ERROR: let differenceBetweenDates: any;
        unitDateValue = parseFloat( differenceBetweenDates / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7) ).toFixed(1);
        //Round up on .9
        let unitDateValueArray = unitDateValue.split('.');
        if(unitDateValueArray.length === 2 && unitDateValueArray[1] === '9') {
          unitDateValue = Math.round( Number(unitDateValue) );
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log( Number(unitDateValue).toString() );
  }

}
```

Comment: parseFloat is used to parse a string to a floating point number. differenceBetweenDates / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7) is already a number. So there's nothing to parse.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`parseFloat` only accepts strings in its first parameter. That's the error.

Since you've already got a number there, you don't need to call `praseFloat` on it. Just wrap in parenthesis and call `.toFixed(1)` on the result.

```
unitDateValue = (differenceBetweenDates / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toFixed(0);
```

Comment: Agh, it was right there in my face and I didn't notice it! The error was really throwing me off. I didn't realize the error was on the parseFloat function!